# Add same handler to multiple events in Dart?

Tags: dart, event-listener

Is there a way to add (in a nice way, I mean to avoid multiple listener definitions) same event handler to few events? i.e.

```js
element.on('event1 event2 event3').listen(handleEvents);
```

**EDIT:**
I mean also generic events like `focus`, `blur` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```dart
['event1', 'event2', 'event3'].forEach((event) => 
    element.on[event].listen(handleEvents));
```

Alternatively you can do :

```dart
[element.onBlur, element.onFocus].forEach((stream) => stream.listen(handleEvents));
```

Comment: This is good for custom events, but problem is that if events are generic ie. `keyup`, `blur` etc. it can be that different browsers will have different names for them..

Comment: You should try this code... It works even for `keyup`, `blur` etc.